# ruby variable returns nil after driver.execute_script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to return a very long string of urls separated by commas.  The code works fine in the console but when I execute the script the urls_list, ruby variable, is nil.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'json'


driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 20

driver.get "https://go.urbanairship.com/accounts/login/"
username = driver.find_element(:id, "id_username").send_keys "????"
password = driver.find_element(:id, "id_password").send_keys "????"
submit = driver.find_element(:class, "important").click

urls_list = driver.execute_script( "
     var urls = [];
     for (var i = 1; i < 37; i ++) {
       (function (i){
         $.getJSON('https://go.urbanairship.com/apps/-/list/'+ i + '/per_page=20').then(function(data) {   
            var json = data;
            for (var j = 0; j < json.objects.length; j++) {
              var url = json.objects[j].url
              urls.push(url);
             }  
          });
       }(i));

     }
     urls.toString();

")

sleep 10
puts urls_list # urls_list is nil
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to give the driver a little more of a hint about what to **return** from your script.

As in, change it to:

```
return urls.toString();
```

Comment: now its returning an empty string. I think that the javascript does not finish running..

Comment: Run your JavaScript into Chrome's Console or Firebug...what do you get? You should also implement a success callback so you can debug whether or not each individual GET request is actually making it to it's intended target without any errors: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/  ...I also believe `.getJSON` is an async call, and thus you cannot guarantee when or if the call will be made, or even in which order it's going to be sent off....so perhaps you should explain more about what you are doing and perhaps there are better ways to accomplish it.